# Analytics for SharePoint Intranet

Tags: html, sharepoint, google-analytics, analytics

I'm looking for basic usage analytics to apply to an html page hosted on a company's SharePoint servers. Google analytics likely won't work because of this

```
The Google Analytics JavaScript won't work if your intranet can only be accessed using a domain name that isn't fully qualified, such as http://intranet.
```

The URL for our SharePoint starts with http://teamshare/ ...

My question is: What analytic tools can I use that don't need an install server side, will work on an intranet/unqualified domain name, and won't allow any undesired accesses.

(I suppose there's always the good old 1990s hit counter, right?)

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want an on premises solution.  Angelfish Software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GA javascripts needs a fully qualified domain name because a fully qualified domain name is part of the [cookie spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt). GA uses a cookie to store a client id that is used to stitch individual pageviews into sessions and visitors.

You should be able to use GA without a fqdn if you set <s>the cookie domain</s> storage to "none" when you create the ga tracker and provide a unique client id for each user via some serverside mechanism. [Example from the documentation:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id?hl=en#disabling_cookies)

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
  'storage': 'none',
  'clientId': '76c24efd-ec42-492a-92df-c62cfd4540a3'
});
```

If that doesn't work there is still the [measurement protoco](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en)l - as long as Sharepoint can fill in a few parameters in a image url (at least client id, account id, hit type and page location) you can do at least basic tracking by sending a image request to the GA endpoint.

Comment: Thanks I'll explore these options!

Answer (score 1):

You may actually be able to set up a dummy domain name, and make all your calls to Google analytics refer to that instead of the intranet name. I have used Google Analytics off my local machine, which doesn't even have a static IP, let alone a domain name. The only catch is that every time you call into the analytics library, you have to explicitly set the domain name, rather than let it figure it out automatically.

Comment: Now that's creative. I'll give that a shot. Thanks

Comment: See Eike's answer, you will need to set storage to none for this to work as well. I completely forgot.